# OnItemSelect Spinner Duplicating a Record in Android

Tags: android, spinner

**strong text**

Can any one tell me Why my Record is duplicating on per item selected in Android Spinner..

> OnCreate() method

```
path_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_path);
        path_spinner.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                path_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        if (path_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() > 0) {
                            getitemno = path_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                            getposition = getitemno;

                            new AlgoApiNetCheck().execute();

                            if (path_spinner!=null && path_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)
                            {
                                new AlgoApiNetCheck().execute();
                            }

                            Log.d("Item Position", String.valueOf(getitemno));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

> Async Class OnPostMethod

```
 if (!check) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MapLocationActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, get_path);
            Log.d("Counter", get_path.toString());
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            path_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

How to prevent My Spinner to stop a Duplicating My Record

Comment: @Elder Mensutov numbers like 1,2,3,4,5 on per server search and in Spinner if I click item 2 for example my whole data duplicated from 1 to 5..

Comment: Okay, show me please how you add values in `get_path`

Comment: in doinbackground Mehtod count = count + 1;
                            Log.d("Counter", String.valueOf(count));
                            get_path.add(String.valueOf(count));

Comment: I think my get_path is calling as per item click becox my Async class call on per item select to populate a result

Answer (score 0):

clear get_path list data in below code

```
if (!check) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MapLocationActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, get_path);
        Log.d("Counter", get_path.toString());
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        path_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```